# How to run asp.net core mvc project on visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am learning asp.net core mvc and I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial, when I am trying to run a project by clicking IIS Express button it builds only.

[image]

Comment: Did you try clicking on the IIS Express button?

Comment: Yes after clicking it , only building happens

Comment: I created the project to build it first, but clicking on IIS Expresss can run the project normally. Have you changed any configuration or you try to start a new project to see if it is normal.

Comment: @Chaodeng after a long time of trying it asked me to download some files (I cannot remember name of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check which browser is selected by default, if you have only one browser then change the launch method to your application name, it will be `MvcMovie`

[image]